# How to format version number using Shivas/versioning-bundle?

Tags: symfony, versioning

I am using shivas/versionig-bundle for the first time and the default starter version number is 0.1.0 but I need starter version 1.0.0a

How can I format the number of version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to the default readme of that bundle, the version is determined by:

> - VersionProvider (read the version from a VERSION file)
> - GitRepositoryProvider (git tag describe provider to automatically update the version by looking at git tags)
> - RevisionProvider (read the version from a REVISION file)
> - InitialVersionProvider (just returns the default initial version 0.1.0)

So I guess you could - for example - add a VERSION file. And maybe RTFM.